# How to control back button function php

Tags: javascript, php

For example i have a form that have two complaint table and every table have submit button.

[Complaint information form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGRXX.png)

after i made an update to the table and submit, if i want go back to the previous page. i will use this code

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" class='btn btn-danger' VALUE="Kembali" onClick="history.go(-1);">
```

but it become problem when i have made an update before. so when i click the back button it will change the part that have been update back to old one. it not a problem if im not made an update it will back to the previous page that i want which is table list of complaint.

Comment: you meant this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable and a cookies to save your URL.
for example, if you have this page:
 - complaint information list
 - Add complain information form

in complaint information list, you can add a cookies

```
$URLBack = "your URL list";
setcookie("URLpage", $URLBack, time() + (86400 * 1), "/"); // configure expire
```

in add complaint information form, check cookies.
if it doesn't have any value, set default value.

```
//php code
$URLBack = "set your default URL back";
if(isset($_COOKIE["URLpage"])) {
    $URLBack = $_COOKIE["URLpage"];
}
//end php code

<INPUT TYPE="button" class='btn btn-danger' VALUE="Kembali" onClick="javascript: self.location='<?php echo $URLBack;?>'">
```

Hope it helps.